# Cannot import module from .ts file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I've built reactJS projects before, but this time I just need to be able to run a command from the command line so I thought I'd use node for the task.  However I'm stuck on importing functions from other files.

I have got this in my `main.ts`:

```
import testFunction from './testFunction.js'

async function main() {
    console.log('Node Start Project')
    console.log(testFunction('bobby'))
}

(async () => {
    await main()
})();
```

And in my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "testnode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "main": "node main.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "clarifai-nodejs-grpc": "^8.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "sjcl": "^1.0.8"
  }
}
```

and in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "lib": ["es2015"]
}
```

I want to be able to use Typescript.  The testFunction file contains as follows:

```
    export default function testFunction(name: string): string {
        return 'Hello ' + name
    }
```

But the error I keep getting is:

```
(node:12492) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/bridgeman/Projects/testnode/main.ts:3
import testFunction from './testFunction.js'
```

Things I have tried:

- Adding `"type":"module"` to my package.json file
- Renaming `main.ts` to `main.mjs`
- Renaming `testfunction.ts` to `testfunction.mjs`
- Using `require` instead of `import`: `const testFunction = require('./testfunction.ts')` (This works, but  I can't use typescript in my function then, I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' in the function params`)

Please help, I just want to import the function and  get on with my project.

Comment: If you are using `import/export` then _set "type": "module" in the `package.json`_, as the warning states.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl If I do that, I dont think typescript works then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: `npm install ts-node -D`.

Then: replace `"main": "node main.ts"` with `"main": "ts-node main.ts"` in `package.json`.

Comment: That will work in development but not production as it is a dev dependency. Should be using `tsc` for production, and is also good for development. No need to use `ts-node`

Comment: I think this solved it, but im not sure.  On other stackoverflow answers I had previously installed `ts-node-esm`, and it was failing.  But now with `ts-node` the problem seems to be solved, and the import works as expected.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `tsc` and change the file Node runs to `dist/main.js`. This is because the `ourDir` is configured in your TypeScript config. Node can’t run TypeScript without it being compiled.